# Running core dump files

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

I have a running time limit on a cluster. I can't stop my program in the middle of a calculation and perform serialization therefore I was thinking about using core dumps.
How can I run a core dump without gdb?
If I can't, how can I detach it from gdb after I start the run?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't quite follow your question, but can you just detach gdb after you get the core file?

Comment: This is exactly my question, if I start (gdb) run, I can't detach it because the program runs...